# Constraints for max clique problem (python-constraint API)

Tags: python, networkx, constraint-programming

Hello I am trying to learn CSP using python-constraint API and more specifically I am trying to solve the MAX CLIQUE problem. Currently I am struggling about declaring the right constraints for my programm. From what I have read in some examples I modeled my problem like so:

If node A and node B == neighbors **then** ->
their sum should be 2
**else** ->
their sum should be -2

More specifically I created a simple graph with 1 clique, I added variables that can take values 1 or -1 and added the formentioned constraints between the variables. From what I understand because of constraint collision an empty list is returned as solution. So basically what I am asking is the way I am trying to model my problem (variables taking values only -1 and 1) wrong ? or I am missing something at the constraints. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers!

```
from constraint import * 
import networkx as nx


graph_2 = nx.Graph()
graph_2.add_edges_from([('1','2'), ('2','3'), ('2','4'), ('3', '4')])

nodes = list(graph_2.nodes)


problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(nodes, [-1, 1])


problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a + b == 2, ["1", "2"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a + b == -2, ["1", "3"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a + b == -2, ["1", "4"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a + b == 2, ["2", "3"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a + b == 2, ["2", "4"])

print(problem.getSolutions())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to model problems, but your chosen one seems to be a bit convoluted.

A more standard approach is the basic MIP-model, where there is a Boolean variable for each node (say, `n[i]`) that indicates if the node is a part of the clique (1/true) or not (0/false).

To ensure that all nodes in the clique are connected, a constraint can be added for each pair of nodes `i` and `j` that are not connected in the graph stating `n[i] + n[j] <= 1`. That is, since the nodes are not connected, they can not both be set to one.

The size of the clique is the sum of all the node variables (`clique_size = sum(n)`), and this is the measure to maximize.

Smarter models can be specified with more constraints that propagate more, but the above description is sufficient to encode the problem.

Comment: What I am not sure about is this:
How do I identify if a node belongs to a clique or not? If I don't know this, then how can I even begin to use the logic above?

Comment: The nodes with a corresponding true are in the clique, the nodes with false are not in the clique.